# Export chart from Excel by VBa

Tags: excel, vba

i would ask you for help. I have sub see bellow ... two day it works, but not now ... i dont understand ...

```
Public Sub TMV02_PRINT_ID_FRONT()
start:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    PREUKAZMVPREDNACOPY.Range(PREUKAZMVPREDNACOPY.Cells.Item(1, 1), PREUKAZMVPREDNACOPY.Cells.Item(15, 12)).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim ActiveShape As Shape
    Dim shp As Shape
    
            For Each shp In PREUKAZMVPREDNAPASTE.Shapes
                shp.Delete
            Next shp
    
    PREUKAZMVPREDNAPASTE.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    PREUKAZMVPREDNAPASTE.Activate
    
    PREUKAZMVPREDNAPASTE.Range(PREUKAZMVPREDNAPASTE.Cells.Item(1, 1), PREUKAZMVPREDNAPASTE.Cells.Item(15, 12)).Select
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
              Left:=Selection.Left, _
              Width:=Selection.Width, _
              Top:=Selection.Top, _
              Height:=Selection.Height)
    
    
        cht.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        cht.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    
    cht.Activate
    DoEvents
    ActiveChart.Paste
        
    Dim CisloPreukazu As String
    CisloPreukazu = PREUKAZMVPREDNACOPY.Cells.Item(10, 6)
    psUpraveCisloPreukazu = Replace(CisloPreukazu, "/", "_")
    psUpraveCisloPreukazu = Replace(psUpraveCisloPreukazu, "-", "_")
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    DoEvents
    ActiveChart.Export Filename:="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Zaznamovka\Zaznamove knihy VaVZ 06.1.jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
    
    EOPOS.Activate
    PREUKAZMVPREDNAPASTE.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        GoTo start
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"but not now"*?  What happens? Nothing? A runtime error? The code does something unexpected? Excel crashes?  Have you used the debugger?

Comment: sometimes when this sub is in cycle problem with export ...

Comment: Method  Export of object cahrt failed

Comment: sometimes it work but exporting blank file jpg

Answer (score 0):

i think SELECTION and ActiveChart is not a goog idea.

i use this macro to export a chartobject

```
Sub ExportChart()
  Dim objCO As ChartObject
  Dim objChrt As Chart
  Dim strFilename As String

    Set objCO = Tabelle1.ChartObjects(1)
    Set objChrt = objCO.Chart

    strDateiname = "MyChart.png"

   If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename ) <> "" Then
    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename 
   End If

    objChrt.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFilename , Filtername:="PNG"

End Sub
```

Best regards
Bernd